# Moment DatePicker specify MaxDate

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, momentjs

I am planning to use [moment-datepicker](https://github.com/MakingSense/moment-datepicker) for my web-app, due to it's ease of knockout binding. In the documentation; I didn't see any way to specify max select-able date (i.e user can not select any date after today). How can I achieve [this feature](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate) in moment-datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
  endDate: '2014-10-10'
})
```

According to this [documentation](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#options) you should be able to use operators such as `+50 years` but I haven't tried that.